# How to prevent memory error when running parameter sweep?

Tags: python, keras, parameters, deep-learning

I am currently trying to train a convolutional neural network using keras. I am trying to find the ideal hyper parameters so I am running a sweep by doing about 6 for loops (there might be a better way to do this also).

It runs and saves the results after evaluating one round of the parameters, but then by the second round it says there is a memory error and exits the program.

```py
window_list = [1.0, 1.5]
overlap_list = [0.0, 0.25, 0.5]

    for w in window_list:
        for o in overlap_list:
            print('***')
            print('>Window=%s Overlap=%s' % (w, o))

            with h5py.File(h5path, 'r') as fh:

                train_path = 'window_{w}/overlap_{o}/train'.format(w=w, o=o)
                X_train = fh[train_path+'/features'][:, :]
                y_train = fh[train_path+'/labels'][:]

                val_path = 'window_{w}/overlap_{o}/val'.format(w=w, o=o)
                X_val = fh[val_path+'/features'][:, :]
                y_val = fh[val_path+'/labels'][:]

                test_path = 'window_{w}/overlap_{o}/test'.format(w=w, o=o)
                X_test = fh[test_path+'/features'][:, :]
                y_test = fh[test_path+'/labels'][:]

            # One hot encode the y labels
            y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
            y_val = to_categorical(y_val)
            y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

            print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_val.shape,
                  y_val.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

            stand_list = [False, True]
            filt_list = [16, 32]
            kernel_list = [3, 5]
            batch_list = [16, 32]
            epoch = 10

            acc_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[
                'Window', 'Overlap', 'Standardized', 'Filter',
                'Kernel', 'Batch', 'Accuracy [%]', 'Std.'
                'Loss Diff', 'Acc Diff'
            ])
            print(acc_df)

            # all_scores = list()
            for s in stand_list:
                for f in filt_list:
                    for k in kernel_list:
                        for b in batch_list:

                            param_dict = {
                                'window': w,
                                'overlap': o,
                                'standardize': s,
                                'batch': b,
                                'kernel_size': k,
                                'filter_size': f,
                                'epochs': epoch,
                                'repeats': 15
                            }

                            scores = list()
                            l_diffs = list()
                            a_diffs = list()
                            for r in range(param_dict['repeats']):
                                score, result_dict = evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val,
                                                                    X_test, y_test, param_dict)
                                score = score * 100
                                print('>Standardize=%s Filter=%s Kernel=%s Batch=%s: #%d: %.3f' %
                                      (s, f, k, b, r+1, score))
                                scores.append(score)
                                l_diffs.append(result_dict['loss_diff'][-1])
                                a_diffs.append(result_dict['acc_diff'][-1])

                            acc_df = acc_df.append({
                                'Window': w, 'Overlap': o, 'Standardized': s,
                                'Filter': f, 'Kernel': k, 'Batch': b,
                                'Accuracy [%]': np.mean(scores), 'Std.': np.std(scores),
                                'Loss Diff': l_diffs, 'Acc Diff': a_diffs
                            }, ignore_index=True)
                            # all_scores.append(scores)
            f_path = open(res_path+'summary_'+str(w)+'_'+str(o)+'_df.pkl', 'wb')
            pickle.dump(acc_df, f_path)
            f_path.close()
            print(acc_df)
```

After one full sweep on the first window and overlap, the acc_df file was saved. Then right near the end of the second full sweep, I received a memory error.

What would be the best way to free up memory so that I can run these for loops for a long period of time.

Also, if there is a faster way to do a parameter sweep that would also be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that all models are living inside the same tensorflow graph, they are not automatically deleted when not in use. To solve it call `K.clear_session()` after evaluating our model (at the end of each parameter sweep:

```
import keras.backend as K

K.clear_session()
```

This will clean the graph and prevent any memory issues related to it.